# Is there a way to define per-project key bindings?

Tags: sublimetext2

Currently I define shortcuts for build variants in my global config. Is there a way to do the same, but using `<my-project>.sublime-project` config file?

I tried to define them inside "settings" field - didn't work:

```
"settings": [
  { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+a"], "command": "build", "args": {"variant": "my_variant"} }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to define keymaps outside of `.sublime-keymap` files, which AFAIK need to be stored under the `Packages` hierarchy - for example, in `Packages/User/Default (<your OS>).sublime-keymap`, as Sublime ignores keymap files with other names.

However, for what you're trying to do, there is a workaround. The `.sublime-project` file [supports](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html) a `"build_systems"` setting:

```json
"build_systems":
[
    {
        "name": "List",
        "cmd": ["ls"]
    }
]
```

By appropriately modifying this on a per-project basis you can enable the `Automatic` build system and have your specified one run when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>. More information on build systems is available [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html).